# Aplicación me da error de NaN

Tags: javascript, html

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y quería que me pudieran solucionar una consulta.
Estoy tratando de hacer una simple aplicación que calcula el precio de un boleto con Javascript, pero al momento de dar click en el formulario me da error de NaN.

Les dejo el código:

```js
   
  function calcularBoleto()
  {
   var preciokm = 0.25;
   var dida = parseInt(document.getElementById("dist_ida"));
   var estancia = parseInt(document.getElementById("dias_estancia"));
   var dtotal = dida * 2;
   var boleto = dtotal * preciokm;
   var descuento = boleto - (boleto * 0.3);

   if (estancia > 7 && dtotal > 800)
   {
    alert("Su boleto de ida y vuelta cuesta $" + descuento);
   } 
   else
   {
    alert("Su boleto de ida y vuelta cuesta $" + boleto);
   }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Boleto</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <form action="" method="">
   <label for="dida">Distancia del viaje de ida: </label>
   <input type="text" name="dida" id="dist_ida">
   <br><br>
   <label for="estancia">Días de estancia: </label>
   <input type="text" name="estancia" id="dias_estancia">
   <br><br>
   <input type="button" value="Calcular boleto" onclick="calcularBoleto();">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Si me tiran algún consejo agradezco. Saludos!

Comment: El error está en esta línea: *parseInt(document.getElementById("dist_ida"));*, estás *parseando* todo el elemento, cuando deberías parsear sólo el valor: *parseInt(document.getElementById("dist_ida").value);*. Lo mismo ocurre con el valor de *estancia*: _parseInt(document.getElementById("dias_estancia").value);_. Te faltó agregar **value**. Saludos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te faltaba el `.value`:

```js
  function calcularBoleto()
  {
   var preciokm = 0.25;
   var dida = parseInt(document.getElementById("dist_ida").value);
   var estancia = parseInt(document.getElementById("dias_estancia").value);
   var dtotal = dida * 2;
   var boleto = dtotal * preciokm;
   var descuento = boleto - (boleto * 0.3);

   if (estancia > 7 && dtotal > 800)
   {
    alert("Su boleto de ida y vuelta cuesta $" + descuento);
   } 
   else
   {
    alert("Su boleto de ida y vuelta cuesta $" + boleto);
   }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Boleto</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <form action="" method="">
   <label for="dida">Distancia del viaje de ida: </label>
   <input type="text" name="dida" id="dist_ida">
   <br><br>
   <label for="estancia">Días de estancia: </label>
   <input type="text" name="estancia" id="dias_estancia">
   <br><br>
   <input type="button" value="Calcular boleto" onclick="calcularBoleto();">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

cambia esta

```
var dida = parseInt(document.getElementById("dist_ida"));
```

por

```
var dida = parseInt(document.getElementById("dist_ida").value);
```

Comment: Te recomendaría explicar tu código, pues no queda claro el por que de este cambio además que tu aporte es casi lo mismo que el otro usuario ya recomendó

Comment: ok, gracias por la sugerencia!.